# control that has paging but supports custom format

Tags: asp.net, data-paging

i need to know what control in asp .net 2.0 to use to get this layout:

i need to display 8 videos at a time using 2 rows with 4 columns, but the control should also have paging (to display 8 items per page).

i've thought of using a formview but the paging for formview is per one article content / datarow only.

i'm also thinking of using gridview but i am not so sure if i can get this layout.

any thoughts please.. very much appreciated.. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the above scenario i think yo can make use of DataList control of ASP.NET which can help you to make the controls in columns and rows order. You will have to create a Paging Programatically.

I am giving you the link which can help you to create a paging with Repeater Control.

Preferred: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/01/07/434787.aspx

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=345

http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/3646011/ASPNET-Tip-Creating-Paging-for-a-Repeater-Control.htm

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/Aspnet_Repeater_Control.aspx